# iMacros script is not running properly?

Tags: javascript, loops, firefox, imacros

So right now my script is using iMacros to play it. The file name is called `test.js`

```
var m;
m ="CODE:";
m+="URL GOTO=http://tppcrpg.net/map.php?Map=11";

iimPlay(m);

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var c;
    c = "CODE:";
    c+= "CLICK X=679 Y=459";

    iimPlay(c);

    var macro;

    macro ="CODE:";
    macro +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
    macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";

    iimPlay(macro);

    if(iimGetLastExtract().search("Belong")!=-1)
    {
        alert("Found the text");        
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do here in this macro is go to a link and then keep on clicking a certain coordinate. Then if it finds the text `Belong` it will give me an alert box.

---

Now the problem is that if I click the normal `Play` button (not `Play Loop`) for iMacros it's not running smoothly after the 2nd iteration (which is clicking the coordinate).

It is able to go to the link and use the `Click` command but it will just keep fading afterwards and not do anything on the webpage.

Instead what's it doing is that it's running the script very fast but it's not doing any actions of macroing on the webpage.

There are no runtime errors and the loop will finish and the macro will stop, but it seems like it's not able to interact with the webpage anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of search try to use indexOf . indexOf works better for searching something on web page.

And instead of coordinates try use HTML property of the place the macro is clicking. If the coordinates are something relevant to the process then it's better to use HTML property. Coordinates can be preciseness and miss the target.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) I was able to run my macro smoothly. I changed the `Click` to an `HTML Element` and I used `indexOf`. I see clicking goes very fast and so that's why it just quickly does nothing.

But I have one question. Is there a such thing called a `stopwatch` in Javascript? I want to know how fast it takes me to find the text.

Comment: http://wiki.imacros.net/iimGetStopwatch  Use Wiki for reference. It has a lot of useful examples.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm having the same problem if you're able to help me again with this. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649152/why-am-i-infinitely-looping-and-not-doing-anything-on-the-webpage) Thanks though :) You're a true expert on this I gotta say.